# Is $\mathbb R$ a continuous set?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, real-numbers

This question may seem strange, but here is the idea.

We know that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. We also picture $\mathbb R$ as a line with its points "continuously" placed, in contrast with a set like $\mathbb N$ which is made of "isolated" points.

Then we could believe that uncountability and continuity are the same, but they are not : the set $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ of irrationals is also uncountable, but is contains no "continuous" interval, so is also made of "isolated" points. Then, what justifies us in saying that $\mathbb R$ is a continuous set ?

I guess topology has a say in this, so I anticipate with a second question : could we equip $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ with a topology that makes it "continuous" like $\mathbb R$ intuitively is ?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I take the usual (second-order) axioms of a Dedekind-complete ordered field to be the "definition" of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What you want is continuum principle of cantor which is a unproved problem.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "continuous"  in this context. What is a continuous interval?

Comment: @Nosrati: What?

Comment: functions can be continuous; sets can't.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question is unclear, I think it's related to what I said.

Comment: @Nosrati: I don't know if the question is unclear or not, but *how* exactly does CH relate to this? Nobody mentioned anything about intermediate cardinalities and whatnot. In fact, the OP explicitly points out that there are sets of size continuum which are not "continuous".

Answer (score 1):

The "continuity" of $\mathbb{R}$ is for me a consequence of the fact that it is both order dense (between each $x < y$ we can find a $z$ with $x < z < y$) and order complete: if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has an upper bound, then it has a least upper bound $\sup A$. Topologically these ensure that the reals in the order topology is locally compact (no "small holes") and connected, things that the irrationals, rationals and integers do not have.